# Send command to already started program?

Tags: command-line

For example: I have started VLC by double-clicking on *.avi video file and the movie is running. Is it possible to send some command (ex. fullscreen or pause...) to that same instance of VLC from terminal (knowing PID...)?

This question is not for some practical use, it is just curiosity.

Comment: Fullscreen or not is more a command to the window manager than vlc :) In general, things depend on the cli options of an application.

Comment: Clementine, for example, has really good CLI options, like Play/Pause, Next Track, Previous Track, Seek to, RW/FF, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43156436) from StackOverflow as base to build own command to be sent to VLC. Also check the entire Q/A. It use d-bus for "remote control"

```
dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.PlayPause
```

The last `PlayPause` can be replaced with, e.g., `Play`, `Pause`, `Previous`, `Next`.

Comment: Thank you for the link. 'dbus' is what I have been searching. There is small tutorial at https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-tutorial.html. For finding 'dbus' object paths there is program called 'd-feet'.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whether that particular program has implemented such behavior or not, which will be described on its man page.

There is no general way to do this, however some programs define special behavior for specific signals which they receive. For example if you send a `USR1` signal to `dd` command it will print out the progress status.

Sometimes, depending on the program and the information we have about it, we can change some of its behavior by poking around its files or data in the memory.